# ArrayList.add return String instead of boolean

Tags: java, arraylist

We know that `ArrayList.add` returns `boolean` which indicates `true` or `false`.

Now a customization is required which says when we try and add `null` in arrayList it returns a custom string. Lets say for example it goes like this

```
public String add(Element e) {
   if (e == null) {
      return "StackOverflow";
   }
}
```

Now when I see that hierarchy `List` interface and `Collection` both have return type of `add` as `boolean`, there is no provision of overriding it.

please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: You simply can't override it, as there is no such method in `ArrayList`. You can *overload* it, though; but you'd need another parameter to the method to disambiguate it from `boolean add(E)`. (Or you could give it a different name).

Comment: It sounds like in the context of your overall application, this shouldn't be the job of the list's `add` method.

Comment: "returns boolean which indicates true or false." 

Comment: *"Now a customization is required"* By whom? What you want is simply not possible in Java. You may have to change the Language to fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @AndyTurner *"which is why I say ..."* sorry, overlooked that...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle no worries - I added that in an edit.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is: why do you want to do that? This sounds like some weird idea to probably solve a completely different problem.

Answer (score 4):

How about using:

```
String someMethod(Element e) {
     if (e == null) {
         return "StackOverflow";
     }
     theList.add(element);
     return "someString"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to extend ArrayList (or another list implementation). But you need another name of the method, such as addElement.

```
public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public String addElement(E e) {
        if(e == null){
            return "StackOverflow";
        } else{
            super.add(e);
            return "Other";
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void addElement() throws Exception {
    MyArrayList<String> strings = new MyArrayList<>();
    assertEquals("StackOverflow", strings.addElement(null));
    assertEquals("Other", strings.addElement("other"));
}
```

Comment: but that would still leave you with the option of inserting `null` values with the normal `add` method.

Comment: Then the wrapper from fasseg is an good alternative. If you really MUST use add. But a wrapper is still a wrapper.

Comment: And you can extend add aswell, and throw exception if it is used with null

Comment: you can´t override `add` and throw an exception as that would make you change the method signature (adding a throws clause). You can simply make it ignore `null` values and return `false`, but the missing feedback would make it look weird.

Comment: You can throw an unchecked exception, such as RuntimeException (NPE). To avoid that someone actually uses add. But I would recommend to avoid doing so and instead use a wrapper if you actually just want to limit people the available methods.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot override the add method with the same signature and return a different type**. Since the `add(T t)` method is defined in the `Collection` interface as returning a `boolean`, all methods in the type hierarchy with the same signature must return a `boolean`.

You can however:

*Change the Signature by adding more arguments:*

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public String add(T t, String success, String error){
        if (add(t)) {
            return success;
        } else {
            return error;
        }
    }  
}
```

**or**

*Change the Signature by using a different method name:*

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public String addItem(T t){
        if (add(t)) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }  
}
```

**or**

*Use a wrapper class that uses aggregation of an `ArrayList` to do the underlying operations. But you will have to implement all the methods `get, add, size, etc`*

```
public static class MyArrayList<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public MyArrayList() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public String add(T t) {
        if (list.add(t)) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }
}
```